# Getting second value of the column c# sql

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am working on a grade submission module. How do I get the second second row of the column in my table and put it into the `label1`, the third row I put it into `label2`, and so on?

Example:

```
studentID | Subjects
 12345    | Mathematics 
 12345    | Science
 12345    | History
```

I only want to get the second row of the column subject which is "Science" and "History" and put it into the label and save it to new table. because I always get the first row of the column.

This is my code

```
string sql = "Select * from tbl_Subject where studentID like '" + studID.Text + "'";
cm = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    Subject.Text = dr["Subjects"].ToString();
}
dr.Close();
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are  a number of ways by which you can achieve it, In SQL you create a temporary result set with an additional column using the `ROW_NUMBER()/RANK()`  as the index/sno (use the name as your choice) column and then use this query as a subquery and get the result from the query as `select * from (my query goes here) where <indexColumn>=indexWhichIwantToRead;` or you can load all the data from the query in a `DataTable` via a `DataAdapter`'s fill method.

Comment: You should also take a look at paramatizing your sql queries. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a second row in a table, unless a column specifies the ordering.  Your table does not seem to have such an ordering column.

Answer (score 1):

ROW_NUMBER() can be used to skip the entire row as :

```
string sql = "select * from (Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Subjects) AS RoNum ,* from tbl_Subject) std where std.studentID like @Search  and std.RoNum > 1 ";
cm = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
 cm .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", "%" + studID.Text + "%"); 
dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    Subject.Text = dr["Subjects"].ToString();
}
dr.Close();
```

You can skip as many as rows using `std.RoNum > 1` , with the ordering of row `OVER(ORDER BY Subjects)`

Comment: show the one additional line needed to parametrize and mitigate injection vulnerability, and take upvotes :)